# How to academically write the following statement?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing a response to a review of my article. Can someone tell me how can I state the following sentence in a more academic way? I will appreciate if multiple versions of the following statements can be shared.

"The reviewer is correct in noting/mentioning that statement xyz is dubious."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The reviewer's qualifying as dubious statement xyz is justified.
- Let's first acknowledge as well founded the reviewer's appraisal of statement xyz as dubious.
- The reviewer's criticizing statement xyz for its dubiousness does not suffer the invalidation of any counter-argument, whatsoever.
- Let's first grant the reviewer credit for his/her rejection of statement xyz on the count that it is dubious.
- The reviewer's analysis of statement xyz as dubious is not to be contested.
- The reviewer showed the dubiousness of statement xyz and we must adhere to his/her conclusion.
- The reviewer judged statement xyz to be dubious and his/her reasonning stands the test of counter-argumentation.